# Should tag "Parsing" and "Parser" be merged? How can this be done w/o losing the followers?

Tags: discussion, tags

There are a number of followers to both the tag Parsing, and Parser but they seem similar in meaning.

Rather than retag the questions (and loose the "following status" of one of the tags) is there a clean way to merge the tags without losing the "follower status".

The impact of losing the followers isn't that big (6 users) but I think it's beneficial to know how to merge when the time comes to merge two larger tag populations.

Answer (score 4):

At 2500 rep, one can work to create tag synonymous (see https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms ).  While I am not familiar with all the behind the scenes working, I believe it would merge the two tags so that nothing is lost.

That said, while similar, I'm not sure they are the same or should be synonymed (thats a new word I just made up).  A *pars**er*** is a **thing** - a specific implementation.  While *pars**ing*** is a **concept** or a process that the parser does.

One would use the parser tag, while talking about how to use yacc or biosn or antlr to build a parser for the construction of an app.  On the other hand, one would use parsing if trying to attack how to parse a csv file or other data formats.

Do compare the questions that show up in [parser](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parser) and [parsing](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parsing) to see if the separation of ideas exists.

Thats just my take on it though. I could very well be wrong.

---

To create a synomym for a tag, navigate to the tag ( [parser](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parser) or [parsing](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parsing) ) and click on the appropriate [synonym](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tags/parser/synonyms) link (that one is for parser).

You may also find https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms to be of interest.